# Why did the ghouls refer to Harry as "Great One"

Tags: the-dresden-files

In Jim Butcher's book "White Knight" in the Dresden Files series, when Harry uses Lasciel to speak to the ghouls, they always referred to him as "great one" in their language.  Why did they refer to him this way?  What was Jim Butcher's intentions with having the ghouls refer to Harry this way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limited knowledge provided leaves me to surmise that the ghouls have a subservience culture.

It is possible that his use of magic marks him as a higher caste than the ghouls he is speaking to hence he is a great one.

More probable the ghouls are being obsequious because they dont want to be killed horribly.

Comment: I agree with this. adding on to your answer is the one other example of a non ghoul who has a ghoul's respect: the corpsetaker. the Ghoul who follows him around referred to him as "My lord".         furthermore, when that same ghoul was faced with an overwhelmingly superior force (Sue the T-rex) he revealed himself to be a coward.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible that the ghouls sensed Lasciel presence in Harry and were addressing her, not him.